# PHP Yii CJuiAutoComplete get selected value into a hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

i am trying to get the selected value, into the hidden field. But i don't know where to put the javascript or which function to use.

```
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
            'name'=>'stands',
            'source'=>$teststands,
            // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
            'options'=>array(
                'minLength'=>'2',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'height:20px;',
                'class'=>'form-control',
            ),
        ));

        echo CHtml::hiddenfield('output', '');
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note, I haven't tested it, but I have something similar in my Yii app):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'name'=>'stands',
    'source'=>$teststands,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;',
        'class'=>'form-control',
    ),
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
        'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
            $("#hidden-field").val(ui.item.value);                
            return true;  
        }',
    ),
));

echo CHtml::hiddenfield('output', '', array('id'=>'hidden-field');
```

You may also want to have a look at this forum thread on Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10586-cjuiautocomplete-howto/